# MySQL Triggers not working with columns that have spaces

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have to make time stamps for when columns were updated for about 30 columns, so I've created another 30 columns called "x_lastmodified" and the Triggers are working well for all the columns that don't have spaces in them:

```
IF OLD.`SimpleName` != NEW.`SimpleName` THEN
    SET NEW.`SimpleName_lastmodified` = now();
END IF;
```

...but this next one won't. What am I doing wrong?

```
IF OLD.`Poorly Named Column` != NEW.`Poorly Named Column` THEN
    SET NEW.`Poorly Named Column_lastmodified` = now();
END IF;
```

Comment: How do you query those columns?

Comment: Exactly how I wrote it, using \`these quotes\`

Comment: Is it possible that `Poorly Named Column` contains **`null`**?

Comment: \`Poorly Named Column\` can have null values in it, yes.

Comment: `null != NEW.Poorly Named Column` will always evaluate to **`false`**. (It actually evaluates to **`null`**, which `if` coerces to **`false`**.)

Comment: Try `NOT (OLD.'Poorly Named Column' <=> NEW.'Poorly Named Column')` (using backticks, of course) and see if it works.